# How to fix pacman out of sync with glibc?

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

I seem to have made a dumb move with an Arch Linux installation on one of my desktop PCs: I upgraded pacman (using `pacman -S pacman`), but without upgrading anything else. Now pacman won't run, as it is out of sync with the GLIBC version.

I am not sure what is the best way to fix this, since I need to roll back pacman (plus a couple of other dependent packages), but I can't use pacman to do it, since it's not working. I have the previous version packages in the pacman cache and I have at least one back-up alternative root partition on the machine, so perhaps there is some way to fix using a chroot from there?

Can anyone advise on what is the best way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Note that, on Arch Linux, [partial upgrades are not supported](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/System_maintenance#Partial_upgrades_are_unsupported); you should always upgrade the whole system at once (`pacman -Syu`).
`pacman -S package` would install the version of *`package`* that is currently in your sync database, likely reinstalling the already installed version.
`pacman -Sy` followed by `pacman -S package` would update the sync database and then install the latest version of *`package`* *and its dependencies*, possibly breaking other installed packages that depend on older versions of the latter.
As noted in the wiki page linked above, `pacman -Syuw` followed by `pacman -S package` is not a solution either.

to fix it do the following:

1. Download `pacman-static` binary with wget
2. `wget` [`https://pkgbuild.com/~morganamilo/pacman-static/x86_64/bin/`](https://pkgbuild.com/%7Emorganamilo/pacman-static/x86_64/bin/)
3. `chmod +x ./pacman-static`
4. `sudo ./pacman-static -Syu`
5. Clean all occurrences of `pacman` from `/usr/local/` find them with `whereis pacman`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually found a different solution - to use tar to extract the previous packages manually (based on advice given here: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=95007). That solved the problem, but `pacman-static` looks like a very useful tool.